# Chart.js intersection not working without zero value on Y

Tags: javascript, chart.js, intersection

Here's code that I took from another topic:

```js
var ORDER_STATS = {
  "2016": [0, 400010, 400110, 400110, 401000, 401000, 400100, 401000, 400001],
  "Source": [330865, 332865, 318865, 332865, 320865, 334865, 322865, 320865, 340865],
  "Moving average LONG": [304493, 315040, 325809, 329532, 332643, 330421, 329754, 327309, 326865]
};
var colors = ['206,191,26', '119,206,26', '26,200,206', '236,124,98', '206,26,140', '26,77,206', '236,124,98', '206,26,140', '26,77,206'];

// Definning X
var ordersChartData = {
  labels: ['2022-02-10', '2022-02-11', '2022-02-12', '2022-02-13', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-15', '2022-02-16', '2022-02-17', '2022-02-18'],
  datasets: []
}

Object.keys(ORDER_STATS).forEach(function(key) {
  color = colors.shift();
  ordersChartData.datasets.push({
    label: key,
    lineTension: 0,
    type: 'line',
    backgroundColor: "rgba(" + color + ",0.1)",
    borderColor: "rgba(" + color + ",1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(" + color + ",1)",
    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointRadius: 4,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(" + color + ",1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
    data: ORDER_STATS[key]
  });
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'grey';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Tahoma";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 11;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = 'normal';

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: ordersChartData,
  defaultFontSize: 11,
  options: {
    responsive: true,

    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Intersection realization',
      fontColor: "#444",
      fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
      padding: 0
    },

    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'grey',
        usePointStyle: true
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: "index",
      intersect: true,
      position: 'nearest',
      bodySpacing: 4

    }
  }
});

Chart.plugins.register({
  afterDatasetsDraw: function(chartInstance, easing) {

    var Y = chartInstance.scales['y-axis-0'];
    var X = chartInstance.scales['x-axis-0'];

    zeroPointY = Y.top + ((Y.bottom - Y.top) / (Y.ticks.length - 1) * Y.zeroLineIndex);
    zeroPointX = Y.right;

    yScale = (Y.bottom - Y.top) / (Y.end - Y.start);
    xScale = (X.right - X.left) / (X.ticks.length - 1);

    console.log("aaa1", Y.top, Y.bottom, Y.ticks.length, Y.zeroLineIndex, zeroPointY);
    console.log("aaa2", Y.bottom, Y.top, Y.end, Y.start, yScale);


    var intersects = findIntersects(ORDER_STATS['Source'], ORDER_STATS['Moving average LONG']);
    var context = chartInstance.chart.ctx;

    intersects.forEach(function(result, idx) {
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc((result.x * xScale) + zeroPointX, (Y.end - Y.start) - (result.y * yScale) - ((Y.end - Y.start) - zeroPointY), 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      context.fill();
    });
  }
});


function findIntersects(line1, line2) {
  var intersects = [];

  line1.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    var line1StartX = idx;
    var line1StartY = line1[idx];
    var line1EndX = idx + 1;
    var line1EndY = line1[idx + 1];
    var line2StartX = idx;
    var line2StartY = line2[idx];
    var line2EndX = idx + 1;
    var line2EndY = line2[idx + 1];

    result = checkLineIntersection(line1StartX, line1StartY, line1EndX, line1EndY, line2StartX, line2StartY, line2EndX, line2EndY);

    if (result.onLine1 && result.onLine2) {
      intersects.push(result);
    }
  });

  return intersects;
}

function checkLineIntersection(line1StartX, line1StartY, line1EndX, line1EndY, line2StartX, line2StartY, line2EndX, line2EndY) {
  // if the lines intersect, the result contains the x and y of the intersection (treating the lines as infinite) and booleans for whether line segment 1 or line segment 2 contain the point
  var denominator, a, b, numerator1, numerator2, result = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    onLine1: false,
    onLine2: false
  };
  denominator = ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * (line1EndX - line1StartX)) - ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
  if (denominator == 0) {
    return result;
  }
  a = line1StartY - line2StartY;
  b = line1StartX - line2StartX;
  numerator1 = ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * a) - ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * b);
  numerator2 = ((line1EndX - line1StartX) * a) - ((line1EndY - line1StartY) * b);
  a = numerator1 / denominator;
  b = numerator2 / denominator;

  // if we cast these lines infinitely in both directions, they intersect here:
  result.x = line1StartX + (a * (line1EndX - line1StartX));
  result.y = line1StartY + (a * (line1EndY - line1StartY));

  // it is worth noting that this should be the same as:
  x = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndX - line2StartX));
  y = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndY - line2StartY));

  // if line1 is a segment and line2 is infinite, they intersect if:
  if (a > 0 && a < 1) {
    result.onLine1 = true;
  }
  // if line2 is a segment and line1 is infinite, they intersect if:
  if (b > 0 && b < 1) {
    result.onLine2 = true;
  }
  // if line1 and line2 are segments, they intersect if both of the above are true
  return result;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="650" height="241" style="display: block; width: 650px; height: 241px;"></canvas>
```

It's working great, but if here:

```
"2016" : [0, 400010, 400110, 400110, 401000, 401000, 400100, 401000, 400001]
```

I change first value, `0`, on `300000`, code can't show intersection anymore.

Problem is, as I think, in `Y.zeroLineIndex`.
I've tried a lot of variants, logged to console almost all values and noticed that when first value is zero (like in example), `Y.zeroLineIndex` is 9. But if u change first value to 300000, it becomes to -1.
I am unsure how to fix it after many hours attempting to detect a problem and fix it. Nothing helped.

In JS I'm not good, so requesting for a help

EDIT:
[DEMO][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t3Gu.png

Comment: I made a snippet of your code so we can run it here.   When you say "I change first value, 0, on 300000, code can't show intersection anymore." what does that mean?  do you mean if you change 0 TO 300000 or that you remove a 0?  Please clarify.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss
yes, 0 TO 300000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sat down a bit on your problem and found out that you had a problem setting the height according to the Y-axis. Use this code and you will see that it works in any situation. I made changes on zeroPointY, yScale and on Y value of context.arc function.

```
Chart.plugins.register({
            afterDatasetsDraw: function (chartInstance, easing) {

                var Y = chartInstance.scales['y-axis-0'];
                var X = chartInstance.scales['x-axis-0'];

                zeroPointY = (Y.bottom - Y.top)/(Y.ticks.length-1);
                zeroPointX = Y.right;

                yScale = (Y.end - Y.start)/ (Y.ticks.length - 1);
                xScale = (X.right - X.left) / (X.ticks.length - 1);

                console.log("aaa1", Y.top, Y.bottom, Y.ticks.length, Y.zeroLineIndex, zeroPointY);
                console.log("aaa2", Y.bottom, Y.top, Y.end, Y.start, yScale);

                var intersects = findIntersects(ORDER_STATS['Source'], ORDER_STATS['Moving average LONG']);
                var context = chartInstance.chart.ctx;

                intersects.forEach(function (result1, idx) {
                    context.fillStyle = 'red';
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc((result1.x * xScale) + zeroPointX, Y.top + (Y.end - result1.y)/yScale*zeroPointY, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    context.fill();
                });
            }
        });
```